# Check if a table has X amount of records

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a script which connects to a database and inserts data based on form selections

```
function(tx) {
            ensureTableExists(tx);
            var firstName = firstNameBox.value;
            var playingPosition = playingPositionBox.value;
            var sql = 'INSERT INTO Yellows (firstName, playingPosition) VALUES ("' + firstName + '","' + playingPosition + '")';
            tx.executeSql(sql);
        },
```

What is the best method to search if the table already has say 5 entries. If the database already has 5 entries it would then reject the INSERT statement and inform the user that there is no space.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You should use parameterised queries whichever one anyway. That is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. But the database is relational, it's using SQLite for a PhoneGap Android application.

Comment: Just a simple `SELECT COUNT * FROM Yellows` will tell you how many rows are in the table. You can evaluate the result of that to see how to proceed.  And if you don't know what SQL injection is, you probably should look it up.